# execute query onload page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I want to execute a query during onload. How do I this?
This is my code.
This is the query I want to execute.

```
<?php
    mysql_query("UPDATE `requests` SET `stat_id`= 3 WHERE `proj_id`='".$_GET['projid']."' and DATE(`req_date`)='".$_GET['date']."'");   
?>
```

and I have a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#approve').click(function(){
        var date = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var projid = $(this).parent().attr('class');

        window.location.href="index.php?page=requests&date="+date+"&projid="+projid+"";
    });
});
</script>
```

when the button approve is clicked the page is refreshed, but the query is not executing.

Comment: remark : avoid sql injection

Comment: @HaimEvgi, *improve* will have the opposite effect there :)

Comment: is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You should use PDO too, as mysql_* methods are depreciated  {thats not answering your question though}

Comment: yes.but i just want to figure this out first before i switch.please help?

Comment: Could you add more of your PHP code so I can further help you, or see this code in context to each other? Filenames included please.

Comment: add some error handling to query and output any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in `index.php` for updating table

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE Persons SET stat_id=3 WHERE proj_id='".$_POST['projid']."' and DATE(`req_date`)=DATE('".$_POST['date']."')");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Check [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Then use ajax to call this page

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Index.php",
  data: { projid: projid , date: date }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

[jQuery ajax reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: how will i put the projid in the query sir?
is it mysql_query("UPDATE Persons SET stat_id=3
WHERE proj_id='projid'"); ?

Comment: Check my answer: UPDATE Persons SET stat_id=3
WHERE proj_id='".$_GET['projid']."'

Comment: having an error.index undefined.at the index.php.i guess its not getting the data.

Comment: No. Its correct. Please try with this query
`UPDATE Persons SET stat_id=3 WHERE proj_id='".$_POST["projid"]."'`

Comment: Can you try to put an echo and try the values on the server end?

Comment: its passing the correct values, correct query.but still no update to the database.i guess the query itself is not executing? or am i wrong?

Comment: Query seems correct. are you able to update the tables with hard-coded values in Index.php?

Comment: its like this 2012-01-05.timestamp type.but when i manually update the exact values into the db.there isn't any problem.

Comment: Just confirming, as your last comment was not clear... if you enter correct values directly in the query in Index.php and call the pahp page (by entering the url in the browser), are you getting the database updated?

Comment: no sir.still no update in the database.i hard coded the values and execute the index.php.still doesn't work.

Comment: can you please provide the query you have used?

Comment: mysql_query ("UPDATE `requests` SET `stat_id`= 3 WHERE `proj_id`='1' and DATE(`req_date`)='2013-01-01'");
here sir.that's the query with the hard-coded values.

Comment: mysql_query ("UPDATE requests SET stat_id= 3 WHERE proj_id='1' and DATE(req_date)=DATE('2013-01-01')"); Try this one

Comment: Try this one to confirm, is there any issue i date conversion. mysql_query ("UPDATE requests SET stat_id= 3 WHERE proj_id='1'")
If no error is there, need more details to guess the issue

Comment: thankyou for your help sir @wolf.it's now ok.your help is very much appreciated.i just had a little bit of mistake in the query.sorry for that.

Comment: Welcome... Now the issue is solved... you can do magic now... :)

Comment: @chris: You shouldn't just put unescaped values into a query string! This way, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or better, use a more modern approach using MySQLi or PDO. Moreover, you should use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use ajax for the same,
write this inside your java script

```
var date = $(this).parent().attr('id');
var projid = $(this).parent().attr('class');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: "{stat_id: 3,proj_id:projid,Date:date}",
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
```

the result will be boolean or in form of 0/1.

Comment: last statement is not quite right... `result` will be whatever data is returned by server script and can be in multiple data formats `JSON, HTML, TEXT, XML etc`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#approve').click(function(){
        var elem = $(this).parent(),
            date = elem.attr('id'),
            projid = elem.attr('class');

        $.get("index.php", { page: 'requests', date: date, projid: projid }, function() {   
            console.log('updated!')
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: No quotes  should be around projid.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mysql_query` will return a value, you could make use of this to see if the problem is in the query and if it is being executed.

```
<?php
  //Output GET Params
  echo $_GET['date'] . " " . $_GET['projid'];

 //Escape Slashes in Date http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php
  $date = addslashes($_GET['date']);

  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `requests` SET `stat_id`= 3 WHERE `proj_id`='".$_GET['projid']."' and DATE(`req_date`)='".$date."'");  

  //Check to see if an error has occurred. If so output.
  if (!$result) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  }

?>
```

Javascript: (Hard Coded Values)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input#approve').click(function(){

   //Hard code for now to ensure you have accurate data
    var date = "12/12/12";
    var projid = 15;

    window.location.href="index.php?page=requests&date="+date+"&projid="+projid+"";
});
});
```

Comment: If no output it would seem the query was accepted. You can try to "echo" the GET variables and see they are being passed over. I don't see your MySQL connection is this above your PHP code?

Comment: yes.i've already edited the code and added the connection to the database.but still no update in the database.

Comment: You should check to see if your variables are actually getting passed and parsed properly. I've udpated the code above to show outputting to check.

Comment: What format is your date in? I might need to be escaped and could be causing issues and breaking your query. Also what is the column type in the MySQL table it is being inserted?